# Create a custom pie chart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to develope this pie chart and using [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart) package
How can I add blur effect or a border around a custom shape in flutter.
I have used [this example](https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/presentation/samples/pie/pie_chart_sample2.dart) as a starting point but I can not figure out how to add border or shadow around a custom shape, do you have any suggession how can I develop this pie chart?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution on this? I am looking for exactly the same this...

Comment: @3DExtended Yes, you can check this gist, and improve it if you can. https://gist.github.com/m8811163008/1346d2a9dfae983395256a6dba271b8b